# Customizing LED on S3

Tags: java, android, notifications

This Code works perfectly on my Nexus 4. But on my Galaxy S3 nothing happens.

Any Ideas why?

```
public void test(){
        if(notificationManager == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Mist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)

                .setLights(Color.argb(1, red, green, blue), 500, 0)
                .setContentText("test").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.test)
                .setContentTitle("")
                .build();           


            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `Missed Event` checked in `LED settings` and is your notification generated when the screen is off?

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but somebody maybe can use the answer: the alpha value should be ff instead of 01;